# Sport teams classifications based on age

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, expressions

How do you usually classify different sport teams based on age?

In my country, we always for all sports have four and sometimes five classes which would be determined by players' minimum and maximum age:

> **1)** Children team 
>   **2)** Adolescents team 
>   **3)** Youth team (which its players are older than the previous one) 
>   **4)** Adults team (usually the oldest and/or most experienced players of a club)

I wonder if you could let me know about your standards too and explain them in a manner that I was able to equalize these standards of ours and yours.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not say "my country". Either state the country or don't put that in because it's possible someone here speaks your language. I don't think you mean "your standards" but I also think you can do some research on your first .

Answer (score 2):

Sports teams are classified as "Under 13" (or U13) for example. This would apparently mean that the players in the team are all under 13. In practice, it is usual for it to be interpreted as "Under 13 on the first day of the school year (September 1st)"

For football (for example) a team of "under 13s" could have players who were aged either 12 on September 1st of that football season. This means that players don't have to move teams on their birthday, but play with others from the same school year.

The naming varies from sport to sport. I football, the adult men's team is doesn't have any qualifier (eg "Chelsea"), but if clarification is needed you could say "the senior team". The adult women's team could be "Chelsea women", although many women's teams are dropping the qualifier as demeaning. Then there could be a youth team (U21 or U18 are possible) and then separate teams for U16, U15 and so on down to as low as U5.

> Mark plays for Uxbridge Under 18s football team, but next year he is hoping to play in the senior team. His younger brother plays for the U14s.  His dad coaches the U12 girls, and plays for the Uxbridge veterans.
>
> The youth teams in Uxbridge have been very successful this year with the U16 winning the county cup and the Under 8s coming second in the 5-a-side league.

Comment: Can we categorize them as **youth** and **adults** teams @James K? Does it make sense in English? If yes, then what would you call the team before youth?

Comment: You woulld call it the U16 or U15 or U14 etc team.  The "adults" team is (as I said) called the senior team, but only if necessary to disambiguate it from the youth team.

Comment: I've added some examples